# Leaflet's cluster plugin: how to group markers only when they have the same property

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I use:

- Leaflet 1.3.4
- the cluster plugin: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster

How to do so that the markers of my geojson layer are grouped only if they have the same value on a property ?
The markers are localized on each state of the United States and I want the markers to be grouped only between markers of the same state.
In the geojson layer, a property indicates to which state the marker belongs (feature.properties.state)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Simply make one MarkerClusterGroup per State:

```js
// [state]: mcg
const mcgDictionary = {};

L.geoJSON(myGeoJSONdata, {
  onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    const state = feature.properties.state;
    // Initialize a new MCG for the State, if it does not exist yet
    mcgDictionary[state] ??= L.markerClusterGroup();
    mcgDictionary[state].addLayer(layer);
  }
});

// Do not forget to add all MCG's to the map
Object.values(mcgDictionary).forEach((mcg) => mcg.addTo(map));
```

Note: at low zoom level, all these MCG's will likely overlap.